# What is the RMSE normalized by the mean observed value called?

Tags: error, terminology

I have been using the `Root Mean Squared Error` (RMSE) to measure the accuracy of values predicted using a model. I understand that the value returned is using the units of my measures (rather than a percentage). However, I would like to quote my values as a percentage. The approach that I have taken is to normalize the `RMSE` by the mean value of my observations.

Is there a term for `RMSE/mean` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is called the *coefficient of variation*.  See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18621/6633) for some discussion about 
this parameter, or read the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: +1. Isn't also called: relative root mean square error (rRMSE)? , cc/ @celenius.

Answer (score 2):

In my field (analytical chemistry), `absolute error / absolute value` = `relative error`, so relative RMSE [at mean x] would be understood easily.

I'd clarify that the value I divide by is the average, as often the relative error at the extreme values is used:

- error specification of measuring instruments often is relative error at maximum value
- in (chemical-analytical) calibration the relative error at the limit of quantitation or the lower limit of the actual calibration is important.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a standard term in my field, so I will probably use `relative error` as it sounds a little more self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

It is called Normalised Root Mean Square Error (nRMSE) or Relative Root Mean Square Error (rRMSE). You can use either mean or range as the denominator. Read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation#Normalized_root-mean-square_deviation) article